# Sending a file to vertx eventbus

Tags: java, file, vert.x

I'm trying to upload a file using Vertx, the request is a POST request that contains a PDF, my handler looks something like this (I took the code from an example in github):

```
...
Set<FileUpload> fileUploadSet = routingContext.fileUploads();
Iterator<FileUpload> fileUploadIterator = fileUploadSet.iterator();
while (fileUploadIterator.hasNext()) {
    FileUpload fileUpload = fileUploadIterator.next();

    // Use the Event Bus to dispatch the file now
    // Since Event Bus does not support POJOs by default so we need to create a MessageCodec implementation
    // and provide methods for encode and decode the bytes
    ...

    vertx.eventBus().<"what to use here?">send(Address.UPLOAD_FILE, "", result -> {
        if (result.succeeded()) {
            req.response()
               .setStatusCode(200)
               .write(result.result().body())
               .end();
        } else {
            logger.info(result.cause().toString());
            req.response()
               .setStatusCode(500)
               .write(result.cause().toString())
               .end();
        }
    });
```

According to the comment above, I can not just try something like this (it actually shows an error):

```
vertx.eventBus().<FileUpload>send(Address.UPLOAD_FILE, "", result -> {
```

I have been checking MessageCodec but it's not clear to me how to apply it for this case.

Note: the use of the eventbus is a must for this escenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you upload a file to vertx with http post, the file will be stored in the filesystem.

You have to set the uploads directory in your bodyhandler: http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/handler/BodyHandler.html#setUploadsDirectory-java.lang.String-

The FileUpload Object only holds the meta information to the fileupload, but not the content itself.

If you want to send the file over the eventbus, you have to read it first from the filesystem: http://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/file/FileSystem.html#readFile-java.lang.String-io.vertx.core.Handler-

Answer (score 0):

You can use Buffers for that.
In your route you iterate over files, read the temp file and send it as buffer:

```
for (FileUpload fileUpload : routingContext.fileUploads()) {
    vertx.fileSystem().readFile(fileUpload.uploadedFileName(), (f) -> {
        if (f.succeeded()) {
            vertx.eventBus().send(Address.UPLOAD_FILE, f.result());
            // Also handle response here
        }
    });
}
```

Then receiving verticle may look like this:

```
private static class ReceiverVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {

    @Override
    public void start() {
        vertx.eventBus().consumer(Address.UPLOAD_FILE, new Handler<Message<Buffer>>() {

            @Override
            public void handle(Message<Buffer> event) {
                System.out.println(event.body().toString());

                event.reply("OK");
            }
        });
    }
}
```